# intellij idea - Javafx css file: no suggestions

Tags: ubuntu, intellij-idea, javafx, javafx-css

I have the latest Intellij Idea installed on my ubuntu 16.04 with the latest java(java9) from oracle.

I can create a new **Javafx** without no problem, but the issue is
**The idea won't recognize** javafx   .css file, I mean I can't use
**<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SPACE</kbd>** to auto-complete feature ..

I googled all around the web, but I found nothing
I hope you guys could help me.

I tried to change the java sdk from version8 to version9 but nothing. I set the java9 to the default JAVA_HOME path under ubuntu using the command

```
sudo apt-get install oracle-java8-set-default
```

but nothing.

Comment: Any Help guys ?? please if someone has anything please let me know

Answer (score 2):

I finally fixed it 
I download The Ultimate Version of Idea and it worked just fine :)

for some reason this feature of auto-complete Javafx Css file is not present in The Community Edition .. if you're like me then you need to upgrade from Community Edition to Ultimate.. and that's it.

Comment: Looking at the [feature matrix](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html), the community edition doesn't support CSS editing, so it probably has no auto completion for CSS, be it JavaFX or otherwise.